# NameError: name 'Label' is not definedNameError: name 'Label' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i'm writing a login page in multiple files with tkinter and runpy. but when I start the code I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\grond\Desktop\Very Good Things\main_account_screen().py", line 4, in <module>
    file_globals = runpy.run_path("Register_user().py")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "Register_user().py", line 23, in <module>
    Label(register_screen, text="Registrazione avvenuta con successo", fg="green", font=("Lemon/Milk", 11)).pack
NameError: name 'Label' is not defined
```

I've tried `from tkinter import *`

This is the first file

```
from tkinter import *
import runpy

file_globals = runpy.run_path("Register_user().py")
file_globals = runpy.run_path("register().py")


def main_account_screen():

    global main_screen
    Button(text="Register", height="2", width="30", command=register).pack()
    main_screen = Tk() #Crea finetra gui
    main_screen.geometry("300x250")
    main_screen.title("Login") #Titolo gui


#Form
Label(text="Login o Registrati", bg="blue", width="300", height="2", font=("Lemon/Milk", 13)).pack()
Label(text="").pack()

#Login Button
Button(text="Login", height="2", width="30").pack()
Label(text="").pack()

#Register Button
Button(text="Registrati", height="2", width="30").pack()

main_screen.mainloop() #Starta la GUI

main_account_screen() #Chiama la funzione
```

This is the second

```
def register_user():

    global username
    global password
    global username_entry
    global password_entry

#Username e password
    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()

#aprire file in write mode
    file = open(username_info, "w")

#scrittura info nel file
    file.write(username_info + "\n")
    file.write(password_info)
    file.close()

    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)

Label(register_screen, text="Registrazione avvenuta con successo", fg="green", font=("Lemon/Milk", 11)).pack
Button(text="Login", height="2", width="30", command = login).pack
```

This is the third

```
def register():


    register_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
    register_screen.title("Registrazione")
    register_screen.geometry("300x250")

#Variabili
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    Label(register_screen, text="Inserisci i dettagli qui sotto", bg="blue").pack()
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()


    username_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Username * ")
    username_lable.pack()

    username_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=username)
    username_entry.pack()


    password_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Password * ")
    password_lable.pack()


    password_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=password, show='*')
    password_entry.pack()

    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()

    Button(register_screen, text="Registrati", width=10, height=1, bg="blue").pack()

def login_verification():
    print("working...")
```

For write the code i'm using Atom

Comment: You need to put `from tkinter import *` at the top of every file, not just one of them

Comment: thanks for the reply, but now this error comes up:                                           File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "Register_user().py", line 25, in <module>
    Label(register_screen, text="Registrazione avvenuta con successo", fg="green", font=("Lemon/Milk", 11)).pack
NameError: name 'register_screen' is not defined